# Spark streaming get pre computed features

Tags: spark-streaming

I am trying to use spark streaming to deal with some `order` stream, I have some previous computed features for maybe a `buyer_id` for `order` in the stream.

I need to get these features while the Spark Streaming is running.

Now, I stored the `buyer_id` features in a hive table and load it into and `RDD` and

`val buyerfeatures = loadBuyerFeatures()
orderstream.transform(rdd => rdd.leftOuterJoin(buyerfeatures))`

to get the pre-computed features.

another way to deal with this is maybe save the features in to a `hbase` table. and fire a get on every `buyer_id`.

which one is better ? or maybe I can solve this in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my short experience:
Loading the necessary data for the computation should be done BEFORE starting the streaming context:

- If you are loading inside a DStream operation, this operation will be repeated at each Batch Inteverval time.
- If you load each time from Hive, you should seriously consider overhead costs and possible problems during data transfer.

So, if your data is already computed and "small" enough, load it at the beginning of the program in a Broadcast variable or,even better, in a final variable. Either this, or create an RDD *before* the DStream and keep it as reference (which looks like what you are doing now), although remember to cache it (always if you have enough space).

If you actually do need to read it at streaming time (maybe you receive your query key from the stream), then try to do it once in a `foreachPartition` and save it in a local variable.

Comment: now, I load the precomputed data first and cache these and do the join operation on DStream.

Comment: Yes, very good.
If I may suggest: load it in a RDD and envelope the Join operation in a foreachRDD, as the Dstream is updated every bathcTimeInterval, which is no use in your case.